# Android actionbar background show delay

Tags: android

My actionbar is a custom view, when running the actionbar first show background is original style of android and then render my custom background in 500ms. How to fix this delay issue?

BaseActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.mainBackground);
        ActionBar ab = this.getActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        ab.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your activity's launchMode 'singleInstance'?

Comment: @WoookLiu No, default create by eclipse.